# Como realizar essa query corretamente ? [MySQL]

Tags: sql, query, mysql

Diante desse Banco de Dados:
Empregado(**matricula_empregado**, nome_empregado, rua, cidade)
Trabalha(**matricula_empregado**, **codigo_companhia**, salario)
Companhia(**codigo_companhia**, nome_companhia, cidade)
Gerente(**matricula_empregado**, **matricula_empregado_gerente**)

Preciso fazer essa consulta: "Encontre a companhia que tenha a maioria dos empregados."

Minha query:

```
SELECT c.nome_companhia, COUNT(t.matricula_empregado) AS Qtde 
FROM companhia AS c, trabalha AS t, empregado AS e
WHERE t.codigo_companhia = c.codigo_companhia 
AND t.matricula_empregado = e.matricula_empregado 
GROUP BY c.nome_companhia HAVING Qtde = (SELECT MAX(Qtde));
```

Erro apresentado : Error Code: 1247. Reference 'Qtde' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma seria:

```
SELECT Companhia.codigo_companhia, Companhia.nome_companhia, Companhia.cidade, COUNT(Trabalha.matricula_empregado) AS Qtde
FROM Companhia INNER JOIN Trabalha ON (Companhia.codigo_companhia = Trabalha.codigo_companhia)
GROUP BY Companhia.codigo_companhia, Companhia.nome_companhia, Companhia.cidade
ORDER BY Companhia.codigo_companhia DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Mas como é possível existir mais de uma companhia com o mesmo maior número de empregados:

```
SELECT Companhia.*
FROM Companhia
WHERE Companhia.codigo_companhia IN 
        (SELECT codigo_companhia, MAX(cont) AS Qtde 
        FROM    (SELECT Trabalha.codigo_companhia, COUNT(*) AS cont 
                FROM Trabalha 
                GROUP BY Trabalha.codigo_companhia) foo
        )
```